# Flex 4 ColumnChart: How to color bars differently based on data

Tags: apache-flex, charts

How can I color the ColumnSeries differently based on data. I need something like a labelFunction only for the column fill.
I'm sure it's very easy.

**EDIT**: Attached image for JAX to understand. :)
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the column series fill property as [depicted in the API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/ColumnChart.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Comment: I want to change color according to data: if between 1 and 5 - green, if between 6 and 10, yellow if over 10 red.

Comment: In the series do: `<mx:ColumnSeries xField="Country" yField="Gold" fill="{getColor(yourData)}" />` then in the function: `private function getColor(data:uint):uint{if(data > 0 || data <=5) {return 0x00FF00;}else if(....)}` you get the idea.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. How can I have `yourData` be the data for currently looked at column element please?

Comment: In your example, you used `yourData` variable as parameter for the function being called in the `fill` attribute, i.e. `getColor`. How do I get that `yourData` variable to reference the data of the column currently being inspected as each column has a different value on the Y-axis and depending on that value I want to colour the column. Ok?

Comment: Well, you're the one putting the data in the chart in the first place, and you know what's going to be your x and y field... You can always extract the data you need from there...

Comment: JAX, the column chart displays data from an array of objects like `[{x:1,y:3},...,{x:3,y:10}]`. Each bar is defined by X and Y. I want bars that have y>5 to be red for example. How can I get what y is for a certain bar?

Comment: Edit your original question to show the code you have so that I can properly advise :)

Comment: I've added a screenshot. If it's still not clear now I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Ah, then you want to look at the BarSeries [fillFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/series/BarSeries.html#fillFunction) to add data specific colors.

Comment: Haha, it's that simple. Ok, thank you. You should edit your answer to include that.